# Angular Ionic Capacitor app, Firebase Authentication with Microsoft

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I've built a Angular 8 app, with Ionic 5 and Capacitor and I'm using Firebase authentication (@angular/fire).

I can't get Firebase Auth to work with Microsoft sign in at all in this set up which is the only provider I can use for my particular project.

You can call signInWithPopup/signInWithRedirect and a new browser window is opened on the device outside of the app, you can successfully sign in with MS but the app is suspended in the background and when switching back to it getRedirectResult() is empty, no errors thrown and the user is never authenticated to firebase. I'm assuming this is because there is a browser level state (Ionic being one, the system browser being a different one) and the auth flow is broken when it opens in a different browser.

None of the Ionic native plug ins I've seen for Firebase have MS support.

Any ideas how I get around this?

Comment: any news here in the meantime?